# CSSTransition Group Not Working (undefined) React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am calling in the CSS Transition Group property from React.

In my js file:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

I get this exact error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CSSTransitionGroup' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you use `react-with-addons.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using React with Add-Ons

`<script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.3.min.js"></script>`

http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html

Comment: How to use this addon library in npm?

Comment: @MandeepPasbola You can use each react addon via npm individually.

Read
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html

So for CssTransitionGroup

you install with
`npm install -S -E react-addons-css-transition-group`

then you can require like this

`var ReactCSStransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html